# Regular expression optimisation tool?

Tags: regex

RegexBuddy is a great tool. What I'd like though is a tool that optimises regular expressions; takes a handful of expressions and boils them down to a smaller number. Any recommendations?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what this tool would do? It's not clear from your description.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I guess he expects the typical cases like `[0-9]` = `\d`, `\d\d\d` = `\d{3}`. Of course there are more optimization possibilities, but that`s more than just a replacement and requires some kind of AI. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no magic pill for regular expressions. Simple alternation redundency may be able to have some alternations factored out, but thats about it.

Overall, there is no guarantee of a speed increase, or even a need for one.

The best optimization is experience in writing regex. A badly written regex will always stay bad. A well written and tested one would not want to take the chance of a programatic optimization. This is especially true when using modern extended regular expressions.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using perl, you could use [Regexp::Optimizer](http://search.cpan.org/~dankogai/Regexp-Optimizer-0.15/lib/Regexp/Optimizer.pm) or [Regexp::Assemble](http://search.cpan.org/~dland/Regexp-Assemble-0.35/Assemble.pm).

I don't know of any online tools that do what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a regular expression, it will be compiled and then is a faster version of what you instructed it to do.

E.g. The compiler will not know if you have made a mistake, that will create many back-steps or anything. RegexBuddy is the way to go, to find out what the regex will do, so you can make your pattern more precise.

Answer (score 1):

There is https://www.dcode.fr/regular-expression-simplifier

Will simplify

```
/[aaabbb]{0,}(ab|ac)/
```

into

```
/[ab]*a[bc]/
```

There are some limitations:

> Some regular expressions can not be simplified. In this case, the program will return the same string.

> The program/optimizer is in beta test, and does not work all the time! Moreover, some parentheses, potentially useful for capturing can be deleted and escape characters can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com) for Javascript, Python and PCRE regex engines. It shows diagrammatic flow. We can optimize further based on it.

Next, we have got [Regex101 debugger](https://regex101.com/debugger), which takes us to step by step playback of regex matching.